# apt-get reinstall all packages

Tags: apt, bash, package-management, reinstall

I was facing some problems with my system, after executing:

```
sudo chroot aditya:aditya /*
```

Instead of executing:

```
sudo chroot aditya:aditya ./*
```

So I wanted to reinstall the system.
But before I backed up my data, and reinstalled the system, I wanted to try out some things to preserve my current configuration.
I made a list of all installed packages with:

```
dpkg --get-selections > ~/Package.list
sudo cp -R /etc/apt/sources.list* ~/
sudo apt-key exportall > ~/Repo.keys
```

But Just before I reformatted my system, I wanted to try out some things.
Like:
    apt-get reinstall for all packages.
Could you please tell me a bash script or a list of commands to do it?

Comment: Did you use `chroot` or `chown`?

Comment: To avoid this the next time, use `*` instead of `./*`.

Comment: @Cyrus I used chown. Now what do I do?

Comment: This might help: [Advanced: Reinstall (Almost) All Packages Without Reinstalling All Of Ubuntu](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=735693)